# When change setContentView

Tags: android, fragment

As I can change the setContentView if I 'm in a Fragment

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.j_01_list);
            new ProgressTask(jornada.this).execute();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain with more details your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a `Fragment` you can set your view calling `onCreateView()` like

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.j_01_list, container, false);
    }
```

but this only will happens if you extends from **`FRAGMENT`**

Example of a `Fragment`

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

 View rootView;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.j_01_list, container, false);

     return rootView;
     } 
 }
```

For more information check this [`Fragment Documentation`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [`onCreateView() Documentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

Comment: It's what tells me the log cat: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). As I can thank your answers ? My mail Rafelcf@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.aab;

import android.app.ListActivity;
        import android.app.ListFragment;
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ListAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;

public class jornada extends ListFragment {

    private Context context;
    private static String url = "http://cadetes.esy.es/conexion/jornadas/j01.php";

    private static final String FECHA = "fecha";
    private static final String HORA = "hora";
    private static final String LOCAL = "nomLocal";
    private static final String RLOCAL = "resulLocal";
    private static final String RVISI = "resulVisitante";
    private static final String VISI = "nomVisitante";
    private static final String ESTADO = "estadoPartido";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv ;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.j_01_list, container, false);
    }


    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {

            Log.i("1", "Called");
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        private Context context;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Iniciando....");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.jornadas_row,
                    new String[]{FECHA, HORA, LOCAL, RLOCAL, VISI, ESTADO}, new int[]
                    {R.id.tv_fecha, R.id.tv_hora, R.id.tv_local, R.id.tv_result, R.id.tv_visitante, R.id.tv_espacio});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            lv = getListView();

        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String vfecha = ("Fecha: " + c.getString(FECHA));
                    String vhora = ("Hora: " + c.getString(HORA));
                    String vlocal = c.getString(LOCAL);
                    String vrlocal = (c.getString(RLOCAL) + (" - " + c.getString(RVISI)));
                    String vrvisi = c.getString(RVISI);
                    String vvisi = c.getString(VISI);
                    String vestado = c.getString(ESTADO);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(FECHA, vfecha);
                    map.put(HORA, vhora);
                    map.put(LOCAL, vlocal);
                    map.put(RLOCAL, vrlocal);
                    map.put(RVISI, vrvisi);
                    map.put(VISI, vvisi);
                    map.put(ESTADO, vestado);

                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }

    }
}
```